# Problems with CSS positioning

Tags: html, css

I have, for some reason extra white space at the bottom of my div name 'profile-stuff'. I can't seem to figure out why it is there. What could I be doing wrong.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8kvwC/

My CSS:

```css
#profile-stuff {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 6px 16px -9px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Change `top:-100px;margin-bottom:-100px` to `margin-top:-100px` on `#cover-wrap`: http://jsfiddle.net/8kvwC/3/

Comment: @passerby that's an answer.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Because I saw that Adrift has already given an explanation...

Comment: @passerby Your solution was better, though his is now the same.

Answer (score 2):

In your `#cover-wrap`, change your position to absolute and change the top `-100px` to `50px`.

Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, extending from comment:

Just as @Adrift has explained, `position:relative` elements still occupy the space they require, no matter how `top`/`left`/etc. offset they are assigned.

So to avoid this, change

```css
#cover-wrap {
    top:-100px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
}
```

to

```css
#cover-wrap {
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kvwC/3/

Answer (score 1):

you can use that answer if u want the space for the bottom means you have to add

```
       div{
         float:left;
        margin-bottom:100px;
         }
```